# MySQL: use a value from a select in the select itself

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

First, if someone has a better title please help.

If I have let's say a 'calendar' table with a 'day' column. And I have the following query:

```
SELECT day, day AS testDay, testDay AS test2Day FROM calendar
```

MySQL will complain that "testDay" is an unknown column. Of course you will tell me that this statement is useless, but my statement looks more like this:

```
SELECT day, SOME_CRAZY_EXPRESSION_OF(day) AS testDay, EXPRESSION_OF(testDay) AS test2Day FROM calendar
```

And the point is I don't want to evaluate twice the first expression to use it within the second expression.. So is there a way to use a value calculated in the select as part of the select itself?

Of course I could do:

```
SELECT day, SOME_CRAZY_EXPRESSION_OF(day) AS testDay, EXPRESSION_OF(SOME_CRAZY_EXPRESSION_OF(day)) AS test2Day FROM calendar
```

But I'm trying to avoid wasting. If I have no choice, that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MySQL, you'll want to assign a temporary variable to the value of the expression to be able to reuse it, this should do it;

```
SELECT day, @tmp:=SOME_CRAZY_EXPRESSION_OF(day) AS testDay, 
    EXPRESSION_OF(@tmp) AS test2Day FROM calendar
```

See [this page](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/01/23/optimizing-repeated-subexpressions-in-mysql/) for another example with more analysis on the performance impact.

Comment: This sounds good. Any idea if it works with Yii CBDCritria? Or should I create a new question?

Comment: @nute Well, I can't really comment on Yii, sorry, I think you'll get better answers if you post a new question than if you ask in the comments :)

Comment: It's bad.
In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list does not work as expected. I can't provide an example here, read it in the MySQL official docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 2):

So, you can't use variables, because they are containing value from the previous row (from official docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT (@aa:=id) AS a, (@aa+3) AS b FROM tbl_name HAVING b=5;
```

> The reference to b in the HAVING clause refers to an alias for an
>   expression in the select list that uses @aa. This does not work as
>   expected: @aa contains the value of id from the **previous selected row,
>   not from the current row**.

And thats why i founded a temporary solution that is based on the code fragments.
I'll show an example in PHP:

```
$querySubstitutions = array(
      '%days%' => 'TO_DAYS(table.started_at + INTERVAL (table.period - 1) DAY)'
    );

$query = 'SELECT %days% AS days, <EXPRESSION_OF( %days% )> FROM table';

// Replacing pairs in a query
$query = strtr($query, $querySubstitutions);
```

This solution helps to compact a query in most cases, but i don't know yet how it affects performance.